# "-sh: 2: logout: not found" - message when trying to logout from the server

Tags: logout, sh

When I connect to my server:

```
ssh user@ip.address
```

I login with a password, and then do:

```
logout
```

I get this message "-sh: 2: logout: not found".

1. Why can't I log out ?
2. What does this message mean ? I mean Linux, how dare you.
3. Is this some kind of a logger ? Where does it keep messages ?  I
   feel as an aspiring sys admin, I need to learn more about logger, for
   troubleshooting right ? Where can I learn some BASIC junior level
   things, any suggestions would be tremendously highly appreciated.

Comment: Commands can be viewed with `history`; you can also enter commands (when local) without them being stored in the `history` (unless it's setup to record all commands; which is the default for remote/ssh/etc logins) - but much of this is shell specific.   You haven't specified your OS/release (we support Ubuntu where BASH is the default)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. your login shell appears to be set to `/bin/sh` - which doesn't have a `logout` builtin command (you can use `exit` instead - which will have the same effect in this context)
2. see (1)
3. no, it's just a message from the shell. There *is* a `logger` command however - you can learn about it by typing `man logger`

If you want to use the bash shell's `logout` command, then you can change your user's login shell using the `chsh` command ex.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you steeldriver